# How to change MaterialTimePicker's buttons text color independently?

Tags: android, styles, material-design, timepicker

I am changing color of MaterialTimePicker buttons text by changing `colorPrimary` of my time picker style. But when I change `colorPrimary` - chip in selected state also changes it's color.
What I want to achive is to make **Ok** and **Cancel** buttons text white, and selected chip leave Blue. On the screen my colorPrimary is Blue.

**Is there a way to change buttons text color independently?**

```
<style name="TimePicker" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TimePicker">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/dark_grey</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/light_grey</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="chipStyle">@style/chipStyle</item>
    <item name="materialClockStyle">@style/clockStyle</item>
    <item name="imageButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TimePicker.ToggleButton</item>
</style>

<style name="chipStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TimePicker.Display">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/selector_time_picker_chip_text_color</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think i found a method.
From the source code we can see that these two buttons (**OK** and **CANCEL**) are using `borderlessButtonStyle` :

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/material_timepicker_cancel_button"
style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:minWidth="72dp"
android:text="@android:string/cancel"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/material_timepicker_ok_button"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/material_timepicker_mode_button" />
```

So we can simply override the `borderlessButtonStyle` style in the TimePicker style to change the colors. Like this :

**themes.xml** :

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.TimePicker" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TimePicker">
   <item name="borderlessButtonStyle">@style/borderlessButtonStyle</item>
</style>

 <style name="borderlessButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
 </style>
```

then in the end add this line in your main app's theme :

```
<style name="Theme.StackOverflow" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="materialTimePickerTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.TimePicker</item>
    ...
</style>
```

This will work. Please feel free to improve my answer .

Comment: This worked, however, I am not being able to make a different customization for the positive and negative buttons. Would you know how to do that? buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle and buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle are not working